# Android Printing using custom Print service

Tags: android, printing

I am trying to write a custom android print service. I have followed the instruction mentioned in the below blog:
https://github.com/zaki50/MyPrintServiceProject

I am able to create a service, which executes a print job. But after the job doesn't print any thing. My question is, what is the localId that we should provide. Is it printer ip, name? Also is there any way to know why the print job doesn't work. 
Basically the two methods that I am concerned about are adding onStartPrinterDiscovery and OnPrintJobQueue as mentioned below:

```
  @Override
        public void onStartPrinterDiscovery(List<PrinterId> priorityList) {
            String str =     Settings.Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), "enabled_print_services");

            Log.d("myprinter", "PrinterDiscoverySession#onStartPrinterDiscovery(priorityList: " + priorityList + ") called")

            final List<PrinterInfo> printers = new ArrayList<>();
            final PrinterId printerId = generatePrinterId("D8:49:2F:64:04:DB");
            final PrinterInfo.Builder builder = new PrinterInfo.Builder(printerId, "D8:49:2F:64:04:DB", PrinterInfo.STATUS_IDLE);
            PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder capBuilder = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerId);
            capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER, true);
            capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER, false);
            capBuilder.addResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("resolutionId", "default resolution", 600, 600), true);
            capBuilder.setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR | PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME, PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR);
            builder.setCapabilities(capBuilder.build());
            printers.add(builder.build());
            addPrinters(printers);
        }

  @Override
protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {
    Log.d("myprinter", "queued: " + printJob.getId().toString());

    printJob.start();
    //printJob.complete();

    final PrintDocument document = printJob.getDocument();

    final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(document.getData().getFileDescriptor());
    try {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        final int read = in.read(buffer);
        Log.d("myprinter", "first " + buffer.length + "bytes of content: " + toString(buffer));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("myprinter", "", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            assert true;
        }
    }
    if( printJob.isStarted()){
        printJob.complete();
    }

}
```

My Question is what should be printerId(or localId). How do we know if the printjob has succeeded or failed

Comment: Please include code samples when posting on SO.

Comment: I have edited by question with code samples that I need more info about.

Comment: Have you looked at using print manager and adapter? https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#print-manager

Answer (score 1):

You can do detection of print job status [with other methods in the class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintJob.html):

```
if( printJob.isStarted() ){

}
else if( printJob.isCompleted() ){

}
else if( printJob.isCancelled() ){

}
else if( printJob.isFailed() ){

}
```

In addition, the print service has it's own methods [listed in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService.html):

```
@Override
protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {
    Log.d("printer", "queued: " + printJob.getId().toString());
    printJob.start();
    //...
    printJob.complete();
}

@Override
protected void onRequestCancelPrintJob(PrintJob printJob) {
    Log.d("printer", "canceled: " + printJob.getId().toString());
    printJob.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serg for you inputs. I am currently using PrintHelper class(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper.html)

Comment: Also could you please let me know what localId and PrinterId should. Is it same as ip address or MAC address

Comment: The android spooler are delivering the jobs to the printer. Has any body encountered this issue. I have verified the printerId to pointing to the ip address of the printer

Comment: It did not work by using the DevideAdress for the printerId only. Should I use the DevideAdress for both printerId and printerName?