# Print Service to Thermal Bluetooth Printer RPP02N

Tags: java, android, printing

I'm trying to print from Google Chrome Apps using Bluetooth Thermal Printer. In this case I read some documentation and question regarding [this example](https://github.com/zaki50/MyPrintServiceProject/blob/master/MyPrintService/src/main/java/org/zakky/myprintservice/MainActivity.java) then I used this example to print simple image or text. But the problem on my device only show printing progress and not printing anything. Here what I've done :

I have one class named PrintServices extends PrintService

- onStartPrinterDiscovery :

  ```
   public void onStartPrinterDiscovery(List<PrinterId> priorityList) {
        if (!priorityList.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        // RPP02N 66:12:29:4F:06:1C | 54:47:41:07:70:79 || 66:12:29:4F:06:1C

        final List<PrinterInfo> printers = new ArrayList<>();
        final PrinterId printerId = generatePrinterId("66:12:29:4F:06:1C");
        final PrinterInfo.Builder builder = new PrinterInfo.Builder(printerId, "RPP02N", PrinterInfo.STATUS_IDLE);
        PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder capBuilder = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerId);
        capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4, true);
        capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A3, false);
        capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_INDEX_4X6, false);
        capBuilder.addResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("resolutionId", "default resolution", 600, 600), true);
        capBuilder.setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME, PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME);
        builder.setCapabilities(capBuilder.build());
        printers.add(builder.build());
        addPrinters(printers);
    }
  ```
- onPrintJobQueued :

  ```
    protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {        
        final PrintDocument document = printJob.getDocument();

        final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(document.getData().getFileDescriptor());
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            in.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("myprinter", "", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                assert true;
            }
        }
        printJob.complete();
    }
  ```

Printer services is enabled on device setting. The printer device is pairing with my android device. When I try open some page on Chrome then print using my Apps service, my printer didn't print anything.

- Here my reference from other SO : [Android Printing using custom Print service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398441/android-printing-using-custom-print-service)

Comment: You're probably better off writing your own ESC/POS drivers than using Android's bult in framework. It's easy to print text, and there are only like two different ways to print images.

Comment: @Remc4 I dont get it about "writing your own ESC/POS" means. My needs is make an interface for my web apps for thermal bluetooth that connected to android device

Comment: Thermal printers generally use two protocols: Epson ESC/POS (simpler) and Star (more complex, but more features). It's relatively easy to write your own code that produces ESC/POS commands (google for ESC/POS commands). The printer connects via Bluetooth and you feed it commands. You can also try this library: https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android

Comment: @Remc4 i see, I have able to create connection to thermal bluetooth printer on my other android apps, like find pairing bluetooth device, create bluetooth socket, make IO strean and print, everything is work exelecnt. But this time I dont it is posible to reuse that code to my service apps